# How to add controls in UI and database coloumns in table

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have requirement for loading dynamic controls on my page.i had button addmore>>
when i click that button i need create row containing 3 columns with one dropdown,2 text box controls in my page.how to do this and please try to guide me.my user want to create many rows but initially page he dont want load all those controls..when click add more only we need create..

please send me sample code..

santhosh

Answer (score 0):

You can have a panel created and then on the button click event, create instances of controls and add it to the the panel's control collection.

You can you use p.Control.Add method to add controls to your panel

Comment: i unable to do this.. please try to help me with developed code..thanking you Advance.